# Bash: could a background process detect when the main process is ended?

Tags: bash

Let's say we have:

```
background() {
   : # Loop to do something very important
}

background &

# main process code here
```

Could the "background" process detect when the "main" process is terminated?

Comment: Hint: `$$` will be the PID of the main process. All the usual ways to test if a PID is still available apply.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`$$` refers to the main shell's PID (if you need to get the PID of the current subshell, that's `$BASHPID` instead).

You can use `kill -0` as a portable way (in that it doesn't depend on procfs or other linuxisms, not that in the sense of guaranteed availability outside bash) to test if a process is still running. Thus:

```
if kill -0 "$$"; then
  echo "Main process is still running"
else
  echo "Main process has terminated"
fi
```

Comment: What happens if the main shell ended but its PID gets re-used by the system ?

Comment: @Philippe, ...certainly a concern in theory, less so in practice if you're running a tight loop (or on a more modern distro that lets PIDs be larger than 32768 before they start wrapping), but if we _did_ need to rule that out conclusively it would call for checking procfs (if `kill -0` says the process exists _and_ its start time is prior to the current start time, we can rule out recycling).

Comment: That makes senses. A following question though : let's say a modern distro has 2147483648 PID entries, does the system keep all used PIDs in memory ? If not, how does it know which number to pick ?

Comment: Yes, it keeps all used PIDs in memory -- that's the process table size. But it doesn't have a process table entry for every _possible_ PID, just every _used_ PID. And your `nprocs` quota will be much lower than the number of possible PIDs, so `fork()` will start to fail long before you run out of PIDs.